# Apple Silicon m1 can't importing sklearn

Tags: tensorflow, scikit-learn, apple-m1

I have been finished install Tensorflow env step by step from "https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/"

Tf is working!numpy is working! scipy is working!

[image]

but when i import sklearn package, have an error message like this:

ImportError: dlopen(/Users/mecilmeng/miniforge3/envs/tf/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/spatial/qhull.cpython-39-darwin.so, 0x0002): Library not loaded: @rpath/liblapack.3.dylib
Referenced from: /Users/mecilmeng/miniforge3/envs/tf/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/spatial/qhull.cpython-39-darwin.so
Reason: tried: '/Users/mecilmeng/miniforge3/envs/tf/lib/liblapack.3.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/mecilmeng/miniforge3/envs/tf/lib/liblapack.3.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/mecilmeng/miniforge3/envs/tf/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/spatial/../../../../liblapack.3.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/mecilmeng/miniforge3/envs/tf/lib/liblapack.3.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/mecilmeng/miniforge3/envs/tf/lib/liblapack.3.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/mecilmeng/miniforge3/envs/tf/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/spatial/../../../../liblapack.3.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/mecilmeng/miniforge3/envs/tf/bin/../lib/liblapack.3.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/mecilmeng/miniforge3/envs/tf/bin/../lib/liblapack.3.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/liblapack.3.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/liblapack.3.dylib' (no such file)

How to fix it?

---

### pip list

```
Package                  Version
------------------------ -------------------
absl-py                  0.10.0
aiohttp                  3.8.1
aiosignal                1.2.0
anyio                    3.5.0
appnope                  0.1.2
argon2-cffi              20.1.0
astunparse               1.6.3
async-generator          1.10
async-timeout            4.0.1
attrs                    21.4.0
Babel                    2.9.1
backcall                 0.2.0
beniget                  0.3.0
bleach                   4.1.0
blinker                  1.4
Bottleneck               1.3.2
brotlipy                 0.7.0
cached-property          1.5.2
cachetools               4.2.2
certifi                  2021.10.8
cffi                     1.15.0
charset-normalizer       2.0.4
click                    8.0.3
cryptography             3.4.7
cycler                   0.11.0
Cython                   0.29.28
debugpy                  1.5.1
decorator                5.1.1
defusedxml               0.7.1
dill                     0.3.4
entrypoints              0.3
flatbuffers              2.0
fonttools                4.25.0
frozenlist               1.2.0
gast                     0.4.0
google-auth              1.33.0
google-auth-oauthlib     0.4.1
google-pasta             0.2.0
googleapis-common-protos 1.54.0
grpcio                   1.42.0
h5py                     3.1.0
idna                     3.3
importlib-metadata       4.8.2
ipykernel                6.4.1
ipython                  7.31.1
ipython-genutils         0.2.0
jedi                     0.18.1
Jinja2                   3.0.2
joblib                   1.1.0
json5                    0.9.6
jsonschema               3.2.0
jupyter-client           7.1.2
jupyter-core             4.9.1
jupyter-server           1.13.5
jupyterlab               3.2.1
jupyterlab-pygments      0.1.2
jupyterlab-server        2.10.3
keras                    2.8.0
Keras-Preprocessing      1.1.2
kiwisolver               1.3.1
libclang                 13.0.0
Markdown                 3.3.4
MarkupSafe               2.0.1
matplotlib               3.5.0
matplotlib-inline        0.1.2
mistune                  0.8.4
multidict                5.2.0
munkres                  1.1.4
nbclassic                0.2.6
nbclient                 0.5.3
nbconvert                6.3.0
nbformat                 5.1.3
nest-asyncio             1.5.1
networkx                 2.6.3
notebook                 6.4.6
numexpr                  2.8.1
numpy                    1.22.2
oauthlib                 3.1.1
opencv-python            4.5.5.62
opt-einsum               3.3.0
packaging                21.3
pandas                   1.3.5
pandocfilters            1.5.0
parso                    0.8.3
pexpect                  4.8.0
pickleshare              0.7.5
Pillow                   9.0.1
pip                      21.2.4
ply                      3.11
prometheus-client        0.13.1
promise                  2.3
prompt-toolkit           3.0.20
protobuf                 3.19.1
ptyprocess               0.7.0
pyasn1                   0.4.8
pyasn1-modules           0.2.8
pybind11                 2.9.1
pycparser                2.21
Pygments                 2.11.2
PyJWT                    2.1.0
pyOpenSSL                21.0.0
pyparsing                3.0.4
pyrsistent               0.18.0
PySocks                  1.7.1
python-dateutil          2.8.2
pythran                  0.9.11
pytz                     2021.3
pyzmq                    22.3.0
requests                 2.27.1
requests-oauthlib        1.3.0
rsa                      4.7.2
scikit-learn             1.0.2
scipy                    1.7.1
Send2Trash               1.8.0
setuptools               58.0.4
six                      1.15.0
sklearn                  0.0
sniffio                  1.2.0
tensorboard              2.8.0
tensorboard-data-server  0.6.1
tensorboard-plugin-wit   1.6.0
tensorflow-datasets      4.5.2
tensorflow-macos         2.8.0
tensorflow-metadata      1.6.0
tensorflow-metal         0.3.0
termcolor                1.1.0
terminado                0.13.1
testpath                 0.5.0
tf-estimator-nightly     2.8.0.dev2021122109
threadpoolctl            2.2.0
tornado                  6.1
tqdm                     4.62.3
traitlets                5.1.1
typing-extensions        3.7.4.3
urllib3                  1.26.8
wcwidth                  0.2.5
webencodings             0.5.1
websocket-client         0.58.0
Werkzeug                 2.0.2
wheel                    0.35.1
wrapt                    1.12.1
yarl                     1.6.3
zipp                     3.7.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can install using Rosetta2 Mode.
To work in Rosetta Mode:

If **Rosetta 2** is not installed by default in your M1 Mac, then open the pre-installed **Terminal** app and run the following command:

```
/usr/sbin/softwareupdate --install-rosetta --agree-to-license
```

Rosetta allows us to use apps built for Mac with intel chip.

Several CLI tools do not have native versions built for the new M1 architecture.

Enabling them on your native M1 Mac terminal can be frustrating.

Follow these steps to enable Rosetta:

- Select the app(Terminal) in the Finder.
- Right click on the app(Terminal) and select **Get Info**.
- In **General**, check the **Open using Rosetta** check-box.
- Close the Terminal Info.
- Now when you quit the terminal and open it again.
- If you haven't installed Rosetta yet, then it would prompt you to install it.
- If the popup shows up, then click on **Install** button, then enter your user name and password to allow installation to proceed.
- Close the Terminal and open again.
- Now we have a special terminal that can install tools with Rosetta translation.

To verify that you are using a Rosetta terminal, run the following command and it should output **i386**:

```
arch
```

The native terminal without Rosetta would output **arm64** for the above command.

**Moving forward, all commands we ask you to execute should be done in Rosetta enabled terminal.**

### **Uninstall arm64 brew**

If you have installed brew in the past from the native terminal, it is likely that you have an arm64 build of brew. Having two different builds of brew can cause major problems as the packages with different builds will not be compatible with each other.

To avoid this problem you need to uninstall your current installation of arm64 brew.

You can check which build you have by running the following command:

```
which brew
```

If your installation of brew is the Intel build, then the command should output **/usr/local/bin/brew**. If that is the case you can skip installing brew and just update your current installation by running **brew update**.

If your output is **/opt/homebrew** then your installation of brew is the arm64 build.

You need to uninstall the arm64 build of brew by running the following command from the native terminal:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall.sh)"
```

### **Install Intel brew**

Install [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/), which is the package manager:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

Once done, run the below command to ensure that we make use of the **HEAD** revision:

```
git -C $(brew --repository homebrew/core) checkout master
```

Now verify the installation of the **brew** command:

```
which brew
```

The command should output **/usr/local/bin/brew**, which is the expected path.